# How does the degree of neuronal realism affect computing in a deep learning scenario?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-neuron, neurons, biology

Neurons can be simulated using different models that vary in the degree of biophysical realism. When designing an artificial neuronal network, I am interested in the consequences of choosing a degree of neuronal realism.

In terms of computational performance, the FLOPS vary from integrate-and-fire to the Hodgkin–Huxley model (Izhikevich, 2004). However, properties, such as refraction, also vary with the choice of neuron.

1. When selecting a neuronal model, what are consequences for the ANN other than performance? For example, would there be trade-offs in
   terms of stability/plasticity?
2. Izhikevich investigated the performance question in 2004. What are
   the current benchmarks (other measures, new models)?
3. How does selecting a neuron have consequences for scalability in terms of hardware for a deep learning network?
4. When is the McCulloch-Pitts neuron inappropriate?

---

**References**

Izhikevich, E. M. (2004). *Which model to use for cortical spiking neurons?* IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks, 15(5). https://www.izhikevich.org/publications/whichmod.pdf

Comment: ANN has nothing to do with neurons for now..Did you get confused by the name?

Comment: @DuttaA I am new to the field, but from my brief literature review this seems to be a possibility: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Deep_Learning#Deep_Learning_with_Spiking_Neurons.3F Perhaps I should have asked more explicitly about the current state of the art of using spiking neurons for ANNs.

Comment: What you are looking for is neuromorphic computing, mainstream ANN currently do not possess any similarity to neurons...Since you must be knowing it is still impossible to know how neurons communicate by spikes..But some work is being done by neuromorphic​ hardware although they are very far from exact biophysical models...Memristors though have shown some promise in this field by having a memory of past currents

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/how-are-artificial-neural-networks-and-the-biological-neural-networks-similar-an/5957#5957. Might be of help. https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/what-makes-animal-brain-so-special